# how to fix the phrase error: Expected ','but got ;

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design, web3.py

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.7.3/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

// The contract's name is "CryptoInsurancePolicy"
contract CryptoInsurancePolicy {
    // The address of the policy holder
    address public policyHolder;

    // The list of covered cryptocurrencies
    string[] public coveredCryptocurrencies;

    // The percentage of the portfolio that is protected
    uint public coveragePercentage;

    // The amount of the payout in case of a market crash
    uint public payoutAmount;

    // The market crash threshold - if the market value of the
    // covered cryptocurrencies falls below this threshold,
    // a payout will be triggered
    uint public crashThreshold;

    // The constructor sets the policy holder, covered cryptocurrencies,
    // coverage percentage, and crash threshold
    constructor(
        address _policyHolder,
        string[] memory _coveredCryptocurrencies,
        uint _coveragePercentage,
        uint _crashThreshold
    ) public {
        policyHolder = _policyHolder;
        coveredCryptocurrencies = _coveredCryptocurrencies;
        coveragePercentage = _coveragePercentage;
        crashThreshold = _crashThreshold;
    }

    // The "checkForPayout" function is called to check if the market value
    // of the covered cryptocurrencies has fallen below the crash threshold.
    // If it has, the payoutAmount is set and the policy holder is notified.
    function checkForPayout() public view {
        // Get the current market value of the covered cryptocurrencies
        uint marketValue = getMarketValue();

        // If the market value is below the crash threshold, set the payout amount
        // and send a notification to the policy holder
        if (marketValue < crashThreshold) {
            payoutAmount = marketValue * coveragePercentage / 70;
            policyHolder.notify("Payout triggered! You will receive: " + uint256(payoutAmount);
        }
    }

    // The "getMarketValue" function retrieves the current market value of the
    // covered cryptocurrencies from an external data source
    function getMarketValue() private view returns (uint) {
        // TODO: retrieve market value from external data source
        return 0;
    }

    function withdrawPayout() public {
    // Only the policy holder can withdraw the payout
    require(msg.sender == policyHolder, "Only the policy holder can withdraw the payout.");

    // Check if a payout is available
    require(payoutAmount > 0, "No payout is available to withdraw.");

    // Send the payout to the policy holder
    policyHolder.transfer(payoutAmount);

    // Reset the payout amount to 0
    payoutAmount = 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthesis or round bracket in your code.

```
policyHolder.notify("Payout triggered! You will receive: " + uint256(payoutAmount));
```

Although, this code has multiple errors, not declaring a variable is one of them.

Comment: thank you and I have one more question how to declare a variable

Comment: why I asked how to declare a variable because when I add the parenthesis it says thisfrom solidity:
TypeError: Operator + not compatible with types literal_string "Payout triggered! You will receive: " and uint256.
49 |             policyHolder.notify("Payout triggered! You will receive: " + uint256(payoutAmount));
from solidity:
TypeError: Member "notify" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in address.
49 |  policyHolder.notify("Payout triggered! You will receive: " + uint256(payoutAmount));